# Select count statement from 4 different sql tables

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables with the following structure:

```
**FiltersMain**
FilterMain_ID
FilterMain_Name_GR
FilterMain_Name_EN

**FiltersSub**
FilterSub_ID
FilterMain_ID
FilterSub_Name_GR
FilterSub_Name_EN

**cm**
cm_ID
product_id
Cat_Main_ID


**Filtra**
f_Id
product_id
FilterMain_ID
FilterSub_ID
```

The only known things I have at this time are the followings:

`FilterMain_ID` of the `FiltersMain` table (which is 555)

`Cat_Main_ID` of the `cm` table (which is 222)

I want to count (with the `select count` method) the total number of records in the `Filtra` table BUT with followings conditions:

Having the already known `FilterMain_ID` of the `FiltersMain` table (which is 555) and the already known `Cat_Main_ID` of the `cm` table (which is 222).

I have already tried the following select count statement, but I am getting completely wrong result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records

FROM

FiltersMain,
FiltersSub,
Filtra,
cm

WHERE

FiltersMain.FilterMain_ID = FiltersSub.FilterMain_ID
Filtra.FilterMain_ID = FiltersMain.FilterMain_ID
cm.Cat_Main_ID = 222
cm.product_id = Filtra.product_id
```

I am completely confused at this moment so any kind any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Instead of the irrelevant tag asp-classic, please [edit] your question to include the tag for the relevant rdbms. Also, sample data is best served as DDL+DML, and show the desired results.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Jim Jones mssql 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is what you're looking for ?

```
SELECT COUNT(fa.f_Id) AS total_records
FROM Filtra fa
LEFT JOIN FiltersMain fm ON fm.FilterMain_ID = fa.FilterMain_ID
LEFT JOIN FiltersSub fs ON fs.FilterSub_ID = fa.FilterSub_ID
LEFT JOIN cm c ON c.product_id = fa.product_id AND c.Cat_Main_ID = 222
```

Comment: I have only 2 records in the table but your statement giving me 4!

Comment: @user2986570 probably it's duplicated, use `COUNT(DISTINCT fa.f_Id)` if this didn't solve it, please provide a sample data to verify my answer.

Comment: missed the only actual filter in his where clause.  cm.Cat_Main_ID = 222

Comment: @iSR5 Υou saved my life!

I must do some more tests, but with the first look I believe that now is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
(Select Count(*) as FiltersMainCount from FiltersMain where 
FilterMain_ID='555') as FiltersMainCount 
(Select Count(*) as FiltersSubCount from FiltersSub where 
FilterMain_ID='555') as FiltersSubCount   
(Select Count(*) as cmCount from cm where Cat_Main_ID='222') as cmCount
(Select Count(*) as FiltraCount from Filtra where FilterMain_ID='555') as 
FiltraCount
```

Comment: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.